# Loop through each column of first row in table with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am working with Jquery and trying to create a html `table` first and then trying to access all the `columns` of first `row` only. How can I do this? I am trying the below but not working

```
$("#myTable" tr:first td:eq(0)").attr("innerHTML",sometext);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try,

```
$("#myTable tr:first td").each(function(){
       //iterate those TDS over here.
});
```